Battery monitoring system
I'm currently building a battery pack with the configuration 4S4P for an IoT based battery monitoring system, I'm seeking to attach individual wires to both terminals of each batteries in the pack. However, nickel strips will be welded on top of the batteries forming the series and parallel configuration. Hence, my initial idea was to strip the jumper wire and place a Kapton tape on top of the wire underneath the nickel strip so that it acts as an insulator between the nickel strip and the wire so that the wire could be use to connect to sensors for the monitoring of voltage and current specifically the INA219 sensor while still maintaining the series and parallel connection. However, this method couldn't work. Is there any other method to perform this?

Parallel is not series. Figure out what you need. If you need different connections at different times, you will have to figure out how to switch between them.

Cells are either connected in parallel or they are not, and then you can measure individual cell voltages. Please explain more details of the intention of your circuit.
